# Variable change is shown in the unity inspector but doesn't actually take place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to c#, unity and coding in general. I am trying to make a controllable 3d character that can crouch, jump and sprint. Sprinting currently does not work because of what i described in the title: the player's speed is updated in the unity inspector but does not actually change in-game.

full player movement script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{


    public CharacterController controller;

    
    public float gravity = -9.807f;

    public Transform groundCheck;

    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;

    public LayerMask groundMask;

    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public float crouchHeight = 0.9f;

    public float playerPushPower = 2.0f;

    public float speed = 16f;

    public float sprintSpeed = 1.5f;

    public float crouchSpeed = 0.5f;

    private float baseSpeed = 16f;

    
    bool isGrounded;

    bool isSprinting = false;

    bool isCrouching = false;

    bool isJumping = false;
    
    bool isStanding = true;
    






    Vector3 velocity;







    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;


        playerPushPower = speed / 8;

        



        // no rigidbody
        if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
            return;

        // We dont want to push objects below us
        if (hit.moveDirection.y < -0.3f)
            return;

        // Calculate push direction from move direction,
        // we only push objects to the sides never up and down
        Vector3 pushDir = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);

        // If you know how fast your character is trying to move,
        // then you can also multiply the push velocity by that.

        


    


        // Apply the push
        body.velocity = pushDir * playerPushPower;
    }
    
    
    

   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);


        controller.height = 3.8f;

        



        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        { 
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        


      

      if(Input.GetKey("left ctrl") && isGrounded) 
      {
        speed = speed * crouchSpeed;
        isCrouching = true;
        isStanding = false;
        

      }
      else 
      {
        speed = 16f;
        isCrouching = false;
        isStanding = true;
    
      }

      
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded && isStanding)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
            isJumping = true;
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);




        if(Input.GetKey("left shift") && isGrounded && isStanding) 
      {
        speed = speed * sprintSpeed;
        isSprinting = true;
        
      }
      else 
      {
        speed = 16f;
        isSprinting = false;
      }





        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See how the speed is calculate and apply to move the character :

```cs
void Update()
{
    ...
    // 1) Reset the speed to 16 if left ctrl isn't pressed
    if(Input.GetKey("left ctrl") && isGrounded)
    {
        speed = speed * crouchSpeed;
        isCrouching = true;
        isStanding = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        speed = 16f;
        isCrouching = false;
        isStanding = true;
    }
    ...
    // 2) Move the character according to speed
    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    ...
    // 3) Apply the sprint factor to speed
    if(Input.GetKey("left shift") && isGrounded && isStanding) 
    {
        speed = speed * sprintSpeed;
        isSprinting = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        speed = 16f;
        isSprinting = false;
    }
}
```

As you see the sprint factor is ignored, because the character is moved before the sprint factor is applied.
The solution is to apply the sprint factor before moving the character.

```cs
void Update()
{
    ...
    // 1) Reset the speed to 16 if left ctrl isn't pressed
    if(Input.GetKey("left ctrl") && isGrounded)
    {
        speed = speed * crouchSpeed;
        isCrouching = true;
        isStanding = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        speed = 16f;
        isCrouching = false;
        isStanding = true;
    }
    ...
    // 2) Apply the sprint factor to speed
    if(Input.GetKey("left shift") && isGrounded && isStanding) 
    {
        speed = speed * sprintSpeed;
        isSprinting = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        speed = 16f;
        isSprinting = false;
    }
    ...
    // 2) Move the character according to speed (included the sprint factor)
    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    ...
}
```

Bonus : the speed isn't reinitialised when the key left ctrl is pressed.
Then speed decrease each frame. I don't think it's expected.

Comment: First of all, thanks SO MUCH for the answer. Second of all, could you elaborate more on this: "Bonus : the speed isn't reinitialised when the key left ctrl is pressed. Then speed decrease each frame. I don't think it's expected." I'm not sure i understand.

Comment: Play the game and try to do a crouched move... I think you will quickly understand

Comment: I see, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: I think the reset of speed need be in all case. Just put `speed = 16f;` as first line in the method `Update`.